# Angular 2 why use guards rather than just deactivate the links you don't want clicked?

Tags: angular

I am currently learning Angular 2 and am on the subject of guards.   I understand how they work but I don't understand why they are preferable to simply just disabling the navigation controls that you don't want the user to use?

It seems to me you can do that within the component that owns those controls.  What do you get from having a separate classes that implement the **`CanActivate`** and **`CanDeactivate`** interfaces to drive that logic?  A guard component seems to add a lot of complexity for nut much.

Can someone explain what I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer would be simple: not seeing link does not mean that you can't go there.

What if you are on guarded page, and you bookmarked it? Then in few days you dont have access to it and you try to go there? You will not see any buttons but you have url.

So without guards you will be able to navigate there.

In addition there should be extra check on server side, that user gets data depends on their role, but this is other story

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points made by @Volodymyr I've found that using those guards (particularly `CanActivate`) keeps the component code much cleaner once your app starts to grow.

Defining a guard like the [AuthGuard in the Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) keeps that logic in one place, and you can just apply them as more routes are added.  Any new components don't need to concern themselves with whether they can be routed to, or how that is being determined.

We've found them useful for cross-cutting concerns like authentication & authorisation, defining that logic in guards and keep that out of the component who's job is just display some data.

Another nice side-effect is that on our team of 5 developers, if I want to tweak how the guard logic is implemented I don't conflict with anyone working on those components.

As an aside, also found similar benefits from use the Resolve guard to pre-fetch data.